# Rails: 'if running locally' conditional javascript tag include

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to load jQuery from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js` regularly, in production/development environment, as long as I'm not running locally, but my own local `jquery.min.js`  if running locally (e.g. `0.0.0.0:3000`)

Reason why is that I have to do some development without internet connection sometimes, mostly when riding the subway.

I've been doing a `if RAILS_ENV == 'development'` conditional in the template, but it's annoying to have to change the template every time I need to force 'production' mode locally.

I'm using haml btw.. not that it really matters.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionController has a method [local_request?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Rescue.html#M000417). You will probably have to declare it as a [helper_method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#M000491) to be able to use it in your views:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper_method :local_request?
    ...
end
```